# Zgrep and sed do not match lines that contain minus (-) sign

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, grep

I'm pretty new to bash and I'm trying to use `zgrep` along with `sed` to filter some logs and only get the information required.

Here is the log I have in myfile.log.gz

```
2014/11/22 00:53:15.310 @ 5 @ mex.MIP.utils.CATUtils @ About to start ASYNC Track to CAT of KPI Unsubscription for [msisdn=+528341114903,trackExecutionKey=20140713U5cN61405274548493MEX*5803*40]
2014/11/22 00:53:57.725 @ 5 @ mex.MIP.utils.CATUtils @ About to start ASYNC Track to CAT of KPI Unsubscription for [msisdn=+522281344058,trackExecutionKey=20140904fG6W11409859320970MEX*5925*-1]
```

Here is the zgrep command I'm using.

```
zgrep "ASYNC.*Unsubscription.*track" myfile.log.gz | sed -e '/\-/s/@.*5.*CATUtils.*trackExecutionKey=//g' | less
```

Here is the **expected** output

```
2014/11/22 00:53:15.310 20140713U5cN61405274548493MEX*5803*40]
2014/11/22 00:53:57.725 20140904fG6W11409859320970MEX*5925*-1]
```

Here is the **actual one** I get

```
2014/11/22 00:53:15.310 @ 5 @ mex.MIP.utils.CATUtils @ About to start ASYNC Track to CAT of KPI Unsubscription for [msisdn=+528341114903,trackExecutionKey=20140713U5cN61405274548493MEX*5803*40]
2014/11/22 00:53:57.725 20140904fG6W11409859320970MEX*5925*-1]
```

As you see, first line is not replaced as expected. Why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You told `sed` to only operate on lines containing `-` (the backslash is not needed).

```
/-/ s...
```

See "Addresses" in `man sed`.

The line that is not processed doesn't contain it, so sed doesn't change it.

Comment: Thanks! That's it! I changed the zgrep instruction for `sed -e 's/@.*5.*CATUtils.*trackExecutionKey=//g'` i.e. I removed that part `/\-/`